# make popup always visible devexpress lookup edit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I'm using a dev express lookup edit in  a winforms application.Is it possible to make the popup of the lookup edit always visible ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Show the code. Check on the DevExpress forums.

Comment: `DevExpress` forums support very well. not like `DotNetBar's` :(

Answer (score 2):

It is not quite clear to me the real use-case of making the LookUpEdit control's popup always visible, but the  answer is - "Yes, it is possible".
Here is the idea:

```
customLookUpEdit1.AllowClosePopup = false;
customLookUpEdit1.ShowPopup();
//...

class CustomLookUpEdit : DevExpress.XtraEditors.LookUpEdit {
    public CustomLookUpEdit() {
        AllowClosePopup = true;
    }
    public bool AllowClosePopup {
        get;
        set;
    }
    protected override void ClosePopup(DevExpress.XtraEditors.PopupCloseMode closeMode) {
        if(!AllowClosePopup) return; // this line did the trick
        base.ClosePopup(closeMode);
    }
}
```